# Hibernnate QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

I had a working web project.  I was then tasked to move all of the hibernate code out of the war project and into it's own jar.  I moved the persistence.xml to the META-INF of the new jar.

I am now getting this error when logging in:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User where lower(name) = :userName]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
```

I can see in the logs that the persistence.xml is being loaded correctly,  and connecting to the database, so I know the new jar with the hibernate code is being read.  The c3p0 and the mysql jars are in the WEB-INF/lib directory. I can connect to the DB from mysql-workbench.

This same code works in the old war file, so I know it's not a technical issue like having the wrong case, or mapping to thew wrong table.  Just when I pulled the code out to a different project, and I have it as a maven dependency, -- something is not being read properly.

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE**

tried a few things .  I brought the persistence.xml into the war file's WEB-INF, META-INF, classes that id not work. (I don't think that's the problem anyway as it IS picking up the DB url  name/password.)

I found a suggestion to use the full package name for the class, and something werid happend. This is the code:

```
List<User> users = getEntityManager().createQuery("from com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User where lower(name) = :userName")
  .setParameter("userName", name.toLowerCase())
  .getResultList();
```

And now I get this exception:

```
WARN  04-21 18:18:16 HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User where lower(name) = :userName  (QuerySplitter.java:124)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [userName] did not exist
```

That no persistent class is just a warning,  and the execption is clearly wrong as you can see I set that parameter, and yes I has a non-null value.

Any direction would be a help,
Thank you

**PERSISTENCE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="sessionfactory">     
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>     
    <class>com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.Role</class> 
    <class>com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User</class> 
    <properties>  
      .....          
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EDIT**

So this is strange, when I hard code a name like this:

```
getEntityManager().createQuery("from com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User where lower(name) = 'me'")
.setParameter("userName", name.toLowerCase())
.getResultList();
```

I still get the "Parameter with that name does not exisit"  If I remove that completely:

```
getEntityManager().createQuery("from com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User where lower(name) = 'me'")
.getResultList();
```

I works  (I think,  but the error in the log is from the next DB query)

So something must be wrong with that entityManager  (it;s a javax.persistence.EntityManager)

Comment: Can you please try adding the below to your persistence file < class >path to your user class< / class >

Comment: I had that in there, but no luck

Comment: can you try changing your query from com.xxx.xxx.pers..  to User only

Comment: can you please try by just hard coding any value for userName and see if it works

Comment: I get the original User not mapped exception above.

Comment: roll back the change and put in the full path and hard code any user name instead of passing it dynamically and see if it makes any diff

Comment: see edits, it's the setParamter that;s the problem

Comment: what is the column name it is userName or name, please confirm?

Comment: The column name is "name"  the parameter is "userName"

Comment: Can you try the parameter name as name as well

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below query

```
List<User> users =      getEntityManager().createQuery("from com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User where name    = :name")
  .setParameter("name", name.toLowerCase())
 .getResultList();
```

Comment: WARN  04-21 23:59:56 HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User where name    = :name  (QuerySplitter.java:124)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [name] did not exist

Comment: What Is the case of column in your database is it Name or name or NAME?